# Storing initial content in an ios app

Tags: ios, storage

I have an app that has lots of content initially: documents, pictures, movies; stuff that will be updatable in the future, but static initially.  I'm wondering where this content should be stored, and how.

I'm thinking the content should be stored in the cache directory (as I understand it, the documents directory is meant for user-generated content?).  I'm wondering if the idea here is to have those files in the main bundle and copy them over to the target directory.  If not, what are some good options here?

Answer (score 1):

Generally speaking, this might be a good reference to look at: [Data Persistence](http://mobile.tutsplus.com/tutorials/iphone/data-persistence-and-sandboxing-on-ios/)

Let me know if you have a specific requirement to fulfill.

Comment: Thanks, I'll give this a read.  I'm looking to store 200-500mbs of content that will be updatable/revisable in upcoming versions.  I'm wondering if it would be problematic to just store this content in the main bundle initially, and move/delete it in the first app store update.

Comment: The problem is you cannot modify the main bundle - anything that is there has to stay there. You could save "diffs" to it instead of duping it to the Documents folder. Rethink how you do expose the data and try to avoid copying so much to your documents folder.

Comment: I can't modify the contents of the main bundle even on an app update, when releasing a second version of the app?